# How do I delete a class from my VB.net project

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I added a new class to my project in Visual Studio 2013 using the Class View. How can I delete it if I don't need it anymore? Simply deleting it from the projects hard drive location produces `Module Not Found` errors. I tried deleting all of the text from the classes I don't need. They vanished from the Class View, but their `.vb` files were still present in the project location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your Solution Explorer right click on the file and select delete. That will remove the reference from the proj file as well.

Comment: simple answer that saves couple hours of mine